# Fabric receives permission denied while execute rm -rf

Tags: python, ubuntu, fabric

When I run the fabric.py to deploy my site ton Ubuntu.

I  met the error:

```
[192.168.15.143] run: rm -rf /home/user/project/weather_station/
[192.168.15.143] out: rm: cannot remove '/home/user/project/weather_station/logs/gunicorn.log': Permission denied
[192.168.15.143] out:


Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Requested: rm -rf /home/user/project/weather_station/
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "rm -rf /home/user/project/weather_station/"

Aborting.
Disconnecting from 192.168.15.143... done.
```

My think is that the error is about the permission denied.

I referenced [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1924076)

So I　changed  `run('rm -rf {}'.format(PROJECT_DIR))`into  `sudo('rm -rf {}'.format(PROJECT_DIR))`

but still error.Is there any approach?

Comment: what happens if you use `operations.sudo()` instead of `operations.run()`?

Comment: The error is completely same.Can I set the parameter like `sudo -H rm -rf` in fabfile?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `/home/user/project/weather_station/logs/gunicorn.log` file in use by an active process? If gunicorn is running and using this file as a log file, then "Permission denied." is exactly what should happen. If this is the case, then you need to re-consider what you're trying to do, as you shouldn't be deleting a file that's being used.

In the case of a log file, the obvious solution would be to configure gunicorn to use a different location, like `/home/user/logs/weather_station`, so that it's outside of the path that you're trying to delete.

That point aside, if you stop the gunicorn process before executing this `rm` command, then your command should run successfully.

The broad issue, however, is that (I think) you're trying to delete a log file that's in use. You either need to configure gunicorn to use a different location for its log file, or else you need to end gunicorn before you attempt to delete it.

Comment: thx your reply , I finally fixed the problem by typing `sudo chmod 777 /home/user/project/weather_station/logs/gunicorn.log`

Answer (score 0):

I finally use `sudo chmod 777 /home/user/project/weather_station/logs/gunicorn.log`

Then it does work.